# How to get only the index value as integer not index type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame such as below when I want to get the index according to the desired column value, I get the datatype too.

'''
df.Date[df.Date == '2017-01-01 03:00:00'].index
'''

the output is 'Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')' but I only want to get int value 3.
how can I handle this task?

|  | Date | Hour | Load |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 26659.73 |
| 1 | 2017-01-01 01:00:00 | 1 | 25326.95 |
| 2 | 2017-01-01 02:00:00 | 2 | 23978.32 |
| 3 | 2017-01-01 03:00:00 | 3 | 22652.84 |
| 4 | 2017-01-01 04:00:00 | 4 | 22053.85 |
| 5 | 2017-01-01 05:00:00 | 5 | 21946.24 |
| 6 | 2017-01-01 06:00:00 | 6 | 22060.05 |
| 7 | 2017-01-01 07:00:00 | 7 | 22288.36 |

Comment: Perhaps this question can help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683701/in-pandas-how-to-get-the-index-of-a-known-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `index` like:

```
idx = df.index[df.Date == '2017-01-01 03:00:00']
```

And for scalar select one element index by position - here by first:

```
out = idx[0]
```

Or like @sammywemmy pointed (if you are sure it is just one value), thank you:

```
out = idx.item()
```

Comment: or ``idx.item()``, if you are sure it is just one value