# Every row after a certain value

Tags: pandas, data-science

Here is part of my data:
[image: data]

I want to create a dataframe with every row after the row with L = ball_snap in it. So not only that specific row but every row after it as well.

How would I do that in pandas?

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck? Do you know how to create a dataframe out of an Excel file? Do you know how to select every row after a given index?

Comment: You can get the index of the row with a particular value using any solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683701/in-pandas-how-to-get-the-index-of-a-known-value)

Comment: I dont know how to select every row after a given index @ignatius Reilly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `idxmax` to return the row with *L = ball_snap* and use the slice notation to extract all rows after:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['L'].eq('ball_snap').idxmax():]
```

Input:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C          L
0  8  6  9           
1  3  1  6           
2  4  9  9           
3  1  5  1  ball_snap
4  3  7  0           
5  9  2  0           
6  1  8  4           
7  7  9  8           
8  5  9  1           
9  4  3  4
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   A  B  C          L
3  1  5  1  ball_snap
4  3  7  0           
5  9  2  0           
6  1  8  4           
7  7  9  8           
8  5  9  1           
9  4  3  4
```

**Update**: if you don't want the row with 'ball_snap' use `shift` before `idxmax`:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['L'].eq('ball_snap').shift(fill_value=False).idxmax():]
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
   A  B  C L
4  3  7  0  
5  9  2  0  
6  1  8  4  
7  7  9  8  
8  5  9  1  
9  4  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

To select every row after a given index and/or including that index, you can use a Dataframe's `tail` method with a negative value, for example:

```
idx_first_ball_snap = df.index[df['L'] == 'ball_snap'].tolist()[0]
print(df.tail(-idx_first_ball_snap))
```

This selects the first row with "ball_snap" and also every row afterwards:

```
        K          L
2   47.40  ball_snap
3   46.71           
4  341.60           
5  246.74 
.
.
.
etc
```

Here's the documentation on DataFrame method `tail`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `cummax()`

```
df.loc[df['L'].eq('ball_snap').cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C          L
3  1  5  1  ball_snap
4  3  7  0        NaN
5  9  2  0        NaN
6  1  8  4        NaN
7  7  9  8        NaN
8  5  9  1        NaN
9  4  3  4        NaN
```